# How to customize taxonomy archive template files for subterms?

Tags: custom-taxonomy, children, archive-template

I have a taxonomy called "location" where I have the term "Asia" and the sub-term "Thailand".

Now I created the taxonomy archive template file according to the [Wordpress Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Hierarchy), which is working in the following format:

- taxonomy-$taxonomy-$term.php --> taxonomy-location-Asia.php

Is there a possibility to create a template file also for the subterm, as following:

- taxonomy-$taxonomy-$term-$subterm.php --> taxonomy-location-Asia-Thailand.php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Strictly speaking, according to the [**Template Hierarchy**](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Hierarchy), you cannot. Unfortunately

> taxonomy-$taxonomy-$term-$subterm.php

is not provided for in default, so this file structure will not work. The best you can do here is

> taxonomy-$taxonomy-$term.php

So for Thailand you will name your template as follows

taxonomy-location-Thailand.php

**EDIT**

Just to add to my answer, the file structure that you are looking for, it is doable outside the template hierarchy. You will just need to use the [`template_include`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/template_include) filter hook to "redirect" Wordpress to use that specific template

```
function wpse_template_include( $original_template ) {
    if ( has_term( 'Thailand', 'location' )  ) {
        return get_template_directory() . '/ taxonomy-location-Asia-Thailand.php';
    } else {
        return $original_template;
    }
}

add_filter( 'template_include', 'wpse_template_include' );
```

Comment: Thanks for your solution. taxonomy-$taxonomy-$term.php is working fine, also for subterms. As for the redirect I need another code, as I am having more than one country and I do not want to have a functions-code for each country. Is there a solution to check if there it is a subterm and if yes, take the name of the parent term into the permalink?

Comment: If I understand you correctly here, country will be a term, like ASIA. If a subterm belongs to a term, say Thailand is your subterm of the term ASIA, the template for ASIA should be used, ie, taxonomy-location-Asia.php should be used for all subterms in Asia

Comment: If I am using the format taxonomy-$taxonomy-$term.php, my permalinks will look like following: www.domain.tld/location/thailand. And this is what I would like to have: www.domain.tld/location/asia/thailand. Is there a possibility to realize that for all subterms in one function? Thanks for your support!

Comment: I not very comfortable with rewrite rules, sorry. I would advise you to start a new question on this topic. Sorry that I can't be of any help here